# Desperately trying to understand pygame translucency

Tags: python, pygame

I have been working directionlessly for the past little while trying to figure out how to make a simple function that draws a translucent circle to a given surface in `pygame`. I did my research, and I found that many people suggested I simply draw the circle to a temporary surface with `SRCALPHA` enabled, then blit that surface ontop of the real one I'm drawing to. But I thought that's what I implemented below, no?

```
import pygame

SCREEN_DIMENSIONS = w, h = 800, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_DIMENSIONS)

FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def draw_alpha_circle(screen, colour, position, radius, thickness=0):
    *colour, alpha = colour # Separate the colour from the alpha
    # Note: (assuming colour is a 4-tuple (r, g, b, a))
    #   *colour, alpha = colour
    #
    # is equivalent to:
    #   r, g, b, alpha = colour; colour = r, g, b
    x, y = position
    d = 2*radius

    temp_surface = pygame.Surface((d, d))
    temp_surface.set_alpha(alpha)

    pygame.draw.circle(temp_surface, colour, position, radius, thickness)
    screen.blit(temp_surface, (x - radius, y - radius))

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for evt in pygame.event.get():
        if evt.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running=False

    draw_alpha_circle(screen, (255, 0, 0, 128), (w//2, h//2), 20)

    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

This actually draws nothing to the screen at all. I'm completely stumped as to what's causing it to draw absolutely nothing. Could someone give me a hand please? If it's any help, I'm running Python 3.2.3.

As a side question; why is `pygame` translucency such a hassle to understand? Everything else in the engine is fairly straightforwards, which it should be, but this is remarkably under-documented and difficult to use in my opinion.

**EDIT:** Now I'm confused, because not even the following code works correctly:

```
def draw_alpha_circle(screen, colour, position, radius, thickness=0):
    *colour, alpha = colour # Separate the colour from the alpha
    # Note: (assuming colour is a 4-tuple (r, g, b, a))
    #   *colour, alpha = colour
    #
    # is equivalent to:
    #   r, g, b, alpha = colour; colour = r, g, b

    x, y = position
    d = 2*radius

    temp_surface = pygame.Surface((d, d))
    # Doesn't even draw real alpha, I just wanted to test out if it draws properly without alpha, which it doesn't.

    pygame.draw.circle(temp_surface, colour, position, radius, thickness)
    screen.blit(temp_surface, (x - radius, y - radius))
```

What is going on here? I am utterly perplexed! Am I going insane, and are you guys actually getting circles and I'm just thinking there aren't circles? I swear this pygame translucency is out to get me.

Answer (score 0):

...I'm an idiot.

The fix is to draw the circle on the temp surface NOT AT THE POSITION ON THE NORMAL SURFACE, but at the position (`radius`, `radius`). The following function works perfectly.

```
def draw_alpha_circle(screen, colour, position, radius, thickness=0):
    *colour, alpha = colour # Separate the colour from the alpha
    # Note: (assuming colour is a 4-tuple (r, g, b, a))
    #   *colour, alpha = colour
    #
    # is equivalent to:
    #   r, g, b, alpha = colour; colour = r, g, b

    x, y = position
    d = 2*radius

    temp_surface = pygame.Surface((d, d))
    temp_surface.set_alpha(alpha)

    pygame.draw.circle(temp_surface, colour, (radius, radius), radius, thickness)
    screen.blit(temp_surface, (x - radius, y - radius))
```

I'm not going to delete this question however, I'm going to leave it as a monument to my dumbassery.